# When I run my code I keep getting the error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT. Any ideas?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, sigabrt

This is my first time using Firebase and I'm trying to create a new user on Xcode. Anyone have a solution?

Here is my code on the AppDelegate.swift:

```
import Firebase
import UIKit


@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
```

And here is my code on the SignUpViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth


class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func createAccountAction (_ sender: Any) {
    if emailTextField.text == "" {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please enter your email and password", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    print("You have successfully signed up")
                    //Goes to the Setup page which lets the user take a photo for their profile picture and also chose a username

                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
                    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)

                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My story board looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/efail.png

My error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ7rT.png

Comment: Where in the code does the error occur?

Comment: if you're familiar with breakpoints, add a All Exceptions one and run it again, you'll get more info

Comment: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

I added a picture to my post

Comment: Is there an error message in your console? This is likely a problem with your storyboard, there could be a missing connection between iboutlets/ibactions. Sometimes if you change your storyboard your old iboutlets/ibactions persist. In the right identity inspector, press the right arrow icon to "Show connections inspector" and delete any unnecessary iboutlets/ibactions

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace ?